# I'm trying to use the library react-animated-conversation on my project using vite and typescript react, but it won't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite

I'm doing a personal project, and I want to add an emulated instagram DM's type chat animation on one of the pages, I found the library react-animated-conversation but I can't seem to get it to work, after installation I can't run the project, when I run `yarn dev` it throws this error, is the library not compatible with vite or is this the library the problem here?

```
X [ERROR] Could not resolve "vite-dep-pre-bundle-external:C:/Users/willi/Documents/React/promised-land/node_modules/react-animated-conversation/dist/Conversation.css.js"

    vite:dep-pre-bundle:external-conversion:C:/Users/willi/Documents/React/promised-land/node_modules/react-animated-conversation/dist/Conversation.css.js:1:24:
      1 │ export { default } from "vite-dep-pre-bundle-external:C:/Users/willi/Documents/React/promised-land/node_modules/react-anim...
        ╵                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  The plugin "vite:dep-pre-bundle" didn't set a resolve directory for the file
  "vite:dep-pre-bundle:external-conversion:C:/Users/willi/Documents/React/promised-land/node_modules/react-animated-conversation/dist/Conversation.css.js",
  so esbuild did not search for
  "vite-dep-pre-bundle-external:C:/Users/willi/Documents/React/promised-land/node_modules/react-animated-conversation/dist/Conversation.css.js"
  on the file system.

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "vite-dep-pre-bundle-external:C:/Users/willi/Documents/React/promised-land/node_modules/react-animated-conversation/dist/AnimatedConversation.css.js"

    vite:dep-pre-bundle:external-conversion:C:/Users/willi/Documents/React/promised-land/node_modules/react-animated-conversation/dist/AnimatedConversation.css.js:1:24:
      1 │ export { default } from "vite-dep-pre-bundle-external:C:/Users/willi/Documents/React/promised-land/node_modules/react-anim... 
        ╵                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    

  The plugin "vite:dep-pre-bundle" didn't set a resolve directory for the file
  "vite:dep-pre-bundle:external-conversion:C:/Users/willi/Documents/React/promised-land/node_modules/react-animated-conversation/dist/AnimatedConversation.css.js",
  so esbuild did not search for
  "vite-dep-pre-bundle-external:C:/Users/willi/Documents/React/promised-land/node_modules/react-animated-conversation/dist/AnimatedConversation.css.js"
  on the file system.

C:\Users\willi\Documents\React\promised-land\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1636
  let error = new Error(`${text}${summary}`);
              ^

Error: Build failed with 2 errors:
vite:dep-pre-bundle:external-conversion:C:/Users/willi/Documents/React/promised-land/node_modules/react-animated-conversation/dist/AnimatedConversation.css.js:1:24: ERROR: Could not resolve "vite-dep-pre-bundle-external:C:/Users/willi/Documents/React/promised-land/node_modules/react-animated-conversation/dist/AnimatedConversation.css.js"
vite:dep-pre-bundle:external-conversion:C:/Users/willi/Documents/React/promised-land/node_modules/react-animated-conversation/dist/Conversation.css.js:1:24: ERROR: Could not resolve "vite-dep-pre-bundle-external:C:/Users/willi/Documents/React/promised-land/node_modules/react-animated-conversation/dist/Conversation.css.js"
    at failureErrorWithLog (C:\Users\willi\Documents\React\promised-land\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1636:15)
    at C:\Users\willi\Documents\React\promised-land\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1048:25
    at C:\Users\willi\Documents\React\promised-land\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1512:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  errors: [
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        {
          location: null,          text: `The plugin "vite:dep-pre-bundle" didn't set a resolve directory for the file "vite:dep-pre-bundle:external-conversion:C:/Users/willi/Documents/React/promised-land/node_modules/react-animated-conversation/dist/Conversation.css.js", so esbuild did not search for "vite-dep-pre-bundle-external:C:/Users/willi/Documents/React/promised-land/node_modules/react-animated-conversation/dist/Conversation.css.js" on the file system.`        }      ],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "vite-dep-pre-bundle-external:C:/Users/willi/Documents/React/promised-land/node_modules/react-animated-conversation/dist/Conversation.css.js"'
    }
  ],
  warnings: []
}
```

It shows this error when I run `yarn dev`, how do I fix this?
and an alternative library recommendation would be of great help, thanks

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/4245